# How the intelisense for std::make_shared() know the default constructor arguments? Is it Visual Studio or C++? If C++, how can I implement it myself

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, constructor, c++14

`std::make_shared()` is used to construct an object directly as `shared_ptr` and to call the constructor of given type it takes the arguments of the type's constructor. How can it know the arguments and definitions of the type's constructors? when using templates and ... operator visual studio intellisense can't show the definitions of type's constructors but will only show the generic definition of template, but `std::make_shared()` can show the precise definition of the constructors. is it a feature of visual studio intellisense and specific for standard library functions or is it something I couldn't guess in c++ implementation of `std::make_shared()`? is so, how can I recreate it?

```
template<typename T, typename... types>
std::shared_ptr<T> my_make_shared(types... args) {
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(args...));
}
```

here is how it looks like for std::make_shared()
[std::make_shared()'s intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvByx.png)

here is how it looks like for my example [my example's intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiTzh.png)

Comment: This is probably a feature of MSVS to be helpful and is hard coded into intelisense.  You should check the intelisense settings and see if there is anything about customizing.

Comment: This might be relevant (although it addresses the debugger): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022.

Comment: May I know the version of your Visual Studio?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. I'm quite sure this is the behaviour of older versions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is hard coded into intellisense. You could refer to the [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.9#summary-of-whats-new-in-this-release-of-visual-studio-2019-version-1690).

> Added completion for make_unique, make_shared, emplace and
> emplace_back which provides completion based on the type parameter
> specified.

Below is  intellisense in Visual Studio 2017.
[image]

Comment: Hi, @furkan ünsal May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?